# Не могу установить PyInstaller

Tags: pip, pyinstaller, install

Пишу`Pip install Pyinstaller`

Вот Ошибка:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "d:\proggrams\новая папка\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in 
 _run_module_as_main
     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
   File "d:\proggrams\новая папка\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
     exec(code, run_globals)
   File "D:\Proggrams\Новая папка\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, 
  in <module>
   File "d:\proggrams\новая папка\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
     from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
   File "d:\proggrams\новая папка\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
     from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
   File "d:\proggrams\новая папка\lib\site- 
 packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 11, in <module>
     from pip._internal.commands import (
   File "d:\proggrams\новая папка\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
     from pip._internal.commands.download import DownloadCommand
   File "d:\proggrams\новая папка\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\commands\download.py", line 10, in <module>
     from pip._internal.operations.prepare import RequirementPreparer
   File "d:\proggrams\новая папка\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 9, in <module>
     from pip._internal.distributions import (
   File "d:\proggrams\новая папка\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\distributions\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
     from pip._internal.distributions.source import SourceDistribution
 ImportError: cannot import name 'SourceDistribution' from 
 'pip._internal.distributions.source' (d:\proggrams\новая 
 папка\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\source\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Та же самая ошибка вчера,сегодня ищу решение

Comment: Попробуйте указать путь без кириллицы ! Это может вызывать проблему